# Azure SQL Database の照合順序と識別名について

Tags: sql-azure

SQL Azure の識別名（テーブル名、列名）と照合順序について質問です。
照合順序に「Japanese_CS_AS_KS_WS」を指定したデータベースを作成します。

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
  Id int
)
```

上記のテーブルを作成して、以下を実行した場合

```
select id from test
```

SQL Azure Database ではエラーなく実行されます。
ただし、SQL Server 2016 Express では

```
メッセージ 208、レベル 16、状態 1、行 1
オブジェクト名 'test' が無効です。
```

のエラーになります。
照合順序に「CS」を指定しており、これは識別名にも適用されるので、エラーになるのが正解だと思いますが、Azure でエラーにならないのは仕様でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Databaseは仕様上[DBの照合順序を変更することができません](https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/documentation/articles/sql-database-general-limitations/)。